# Unable to SSH into ubuntu server

Tags: ssh

I get `connection reset by peer` error when I try to SSH into my Ubuntu server using my mobile ISP. However, this error 'disappears' when I change to another ISP. Please what is the likely cause and how do I solve this?

Comment: You've tagged 14.04, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (released 2014.April thus 14.04) had 5 years of support and is now EOL & off-topic here.  If using Ubuntu 14.04 ESM it's off-topic as well (all ESM releases are) so use your Ubuntu Advantage Support.  The only 14.04 questions on-topic on this site now are how to move to a supported release (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)   Please clarify your release of Ubuntu if not off-topic.

Comment: Sorry it is actually 18.04

Comment: If you can SSH using a particular ISP, then you have demonstrated that your Ubuntu server is working properly. This is a good support question for the ISP that won't connect.

Comment: Can you `ping` the server using both ISPs? Can you run `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -dp 12345` in a screen from the working ISP and connect to it from the previously inaccessible ISP? Note that the server will die after a single connection. You can change the default ssh port via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`'s `Port ##`